# Can I display chatter feed tab in visualforce page for Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, chatter, mobile

I'm creating a tab view in visualforce page which will be added in Salesforce1 as mobile tab. I wanted to display chatter feed section as one of the tab in visualforce page.
`ˋ displays standard feed section but it is not supported in Salesforce1.

Is there any other work around to render standard chatter feed section? Is there any other component which is alternative to ˋˋ for Salesforce1?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would mean starting over but lightning components has a component called `forceChatter:feed`.

I have not played with it but given your requirement is a mobile tab it could work. If you didn't want to give up that Visualforce you could try app builder, but would need to join the pilot to enable it. Also VF in App Builder is really just a polyfill and has some down side performance characteristics. And you would need to wrap the `forceChatter:feed component` In your own component to render it available to app builder.

But it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for replies. chatter:feed tag is not supported in Salesforce1. Other option is to use forceChatter:feed component and create lightning component. There is no alternative of chatter:feed in visualforce pages for Salesforce1

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a vf page with `<chatter:Feed>` and create a tabpanel using this vf page and later you can deploy this tabpanel to salesforce1.

Here is a link which can help you more...

https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Winter11/Chatter+Components+for+Visualforce